# Working With Puzzle and figuring how to fix out of bound error

Tags: java, filereader, wordsearch

[My error Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzsLR.png)
Im supposed to read from a file a word search puzzle my problem I keep getting getting out of bound error. I don't know how to properly format a word puzzle to the file's specification. the format of a puzzle generally goes likes this: 
5   5
d e v o l
r e d p h
q c h z j
p o a a f
v a m m n
q t f o x

This is my work so far, I feel that I have reading from a file down but converting that to a word search puzzle. Especially trying to not hard code the specification of the row and column of a word seaarch puzzle.

```
public static char[][] fill(){
    // Created 2 different scanner one for user input and one to read the file

    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    // created a count to add the keywords
    int count = 0;

    //System.out.print("Please enter a keyword to search for.");
    // Asking user to input a valid file name
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid puzzle file name\nYou will be asked for the same file name again later.");
    String wordFile = file1.nextLine();
    FileReader infile;
    boolean validFile = false;
    // Creating a while loop that will keep asking for a valid file name
    while(!validFile) {
        // Using a try and catch to obtain correct file
        try {
            infile = new FileReader(wordFile);
            file1 = new Scanner(infile);
            validFile = true;
        }
        //ask the user to put a valid file name if they are wrong
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid file name, please enter again!");
            wordFile = file1.nextLine();
        }
    }
    String numbers = file1.nextLine();
    String[] fileArray = numbers.trim().split(" ");

    int rows = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[0]);
    int columns = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[1]);

    char[][] fillThemLetters = new char [rows][columns];


    String letters = file1.nextLine().trim().replace(" ", "");

    char [] condensed =  letters.toCharArray(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < condensed.length; i++) {

        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){


            for(int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
            {
                char index = condensed[i];
                fillThemLetters[row][column] = index;
                i++;
            }
        }

    }   
    return fillThemLetters;
}
```

Comment: When you get an error, post the full error message. It'll tell you the line number where it's happening. Tell us which line number that is, because we can't see the line numbers in your IDE from where we're sitting. The sooner you do this, the sooner someone can help -- it's going to be an easy fix, but you won't get any help unless you report the problem correctly.

Comment: You have 3 for loops inside each other this makes it terribly confusing. But use a debuuger to see which one goes out of bounds

Comment: Alright sorry for that. Line 65 and 41 has the problem. Also posted a picture of it.

Comment: It's condensed looking at it I'd guess because you add to i and never check in the third inner loop if you beyond its length when row increases because i has not gone to 0 and is already at condensed size it will overflow condensed eventually

Comment: And which line is 65 and which is 41? As I said before *we cannot see the line numbers in your IDE.*

Comment: line 41:   int columns = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[1]);

Comment: line 65: is the last Curly Brace ( } )

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index out of bounds error is caused here:

```
for(int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
{
    char index = condensed[i];
    fillThemLetters[row][column] = index;
    i++; // <--------- THIS IS WRONG!!!
}
```

See that `i++`? You're incrementing the counter from the outermost loop for no apparent reason. Let the loop handle its own incrementation, which is built in already, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < condensed.length; i++) {  // <--- You already have i++ here!
```

After fixing that, you're going to run into a lot more problems -- your code isn't doing what you think it's doing, but those are all separate questions and should be posted as such separately.

Comment: I think the out of bounds stop occurring, but cannot read from the puzzle still.

Comment: @Nek' OK. So to the left of this answer is a checkmark. Click it to show others that this original question about index out of bounds is fixed. Make sure you've made the change in your code and then post a new question with whatever new problems you see and I'll take a look at it.